# Reset the answers in the flow

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforce-id, flow

My sample flow is as  below:

[image: Flow:]

So basically i am reiterating the flow, if the user clicks on "Yes, I want to create another opportunity". While re-iterating, the previously selected answers are by default selected. Can I reset the answers for questions while iterating over the same flow again?

Any pointers would help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you activitate this "Critical Update" in your org?

> **Behavior Change for Default Values in Flow Screen Fields**
>   There are two ways that a flow screen field can be visited multiple
>   times.
>
> The same instance: The user who’s running the flow enters information
>   into a screen field, clicks Previous and then clicks Next.
>
> Different instance: A screen is used within a loop, and the flow
>   requires the fields to be completed independently each time.
>
> Previously, flows used the last-entered value for a field on a screen
>   if the screen had been visited before, regardless of whether it was
>   the same instance of that screen.
>
> If you activate this update now, flows use the default value (if you
>   set one) for the field when visited for the first time for that
>   instance. If the user reaches the screen because the flow is
>   navigating through a loop, the default value for that field is used.
>   If the user reaches the screen by navigating back&em;or by navigating
>   back and then forward&em;the last-entered value for that field is
>   used.
>
> How can I modify my flows to use a previously entered value? To use a
>   previously entered value as the default value for a screen field:
>
> Within the loop, assign the value of the screen field to a variable.
>   Set the default value for the screen field to that variable.